# How can I resize partition in my case?

Tags: ubuntu, parted

```
(parted) print free
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 322GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
        1024B   1049kB  1048kB            Free Space
 1      1049kB  1000MB  999MB   primary   xfs             boot
        1000MB  1001MB  1048kB            Free Space
 2      1001MB  53,7GB  52,7GB  extended
 5      1001MB  5001MB  3999MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
        5001MB  5001MB  834kB             Free Space
 6      5002MB  53,7GB  48,7GB  logical   xfs
        53,7GB  322GB   268GB             Free Space
```

I want to expand the partition and give it all the maximum available space.
When I try to resize it via resizepart, the error occured:

```
(parted) resizepart 6
Warning: Partition /dev/sda6 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? yes
End?  [53,7GB]? 200G
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.
```

How can I solve this issue and resize it?

Comment: You cannot change mounted partitions. So have to use live installer and unmount swap as it may mount that locking entire extended partition. Then expand extended to include all of the Free Space after the extended partition. Then you can expand /.  Much better to use gpt than old MBR(msdos) partitioning, but change would now erase drive, so best to plan all new or totally reformatted drives as gpt. MSDOS is from the 1980's.